# first click to reach CiviCRM dashboard results in long delay and error message

Tags: drupal, dashboard

I am managing a Drupal site and when I first log in and click CiviCRM menu link, there is a long delay followed by this message:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later.

I have increased the PHP max execution time, and it did help to eliminate this message, but the message is happening again.  I also increased the memory limit to huge.

Can someone tell me how to set some debugging or logging to show me what exactly CiviCRM is doing during this delay?

Drupal 7.5.2.  MySQL 5.5.52-MariaDB.  PHP 5.6.30 as FPM.  CiviCRM 4.7.16.

thanks!

Comment: I have seen something similar to this but perhaps not the same.  This can happen when the Drupal user and contact in Civi don't match - then Civi hangs looking for your dashboard which it can't find because of the mismatch. The tables to check are civicrm_uf_check and the Drupal table users.  This should be taken care of by Administer/Users and Permissions/Synchronise Users to Contacts but I've seen problems there in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the Drupal core to version 7.54 using "drush upc", which reported pending database updates, so I also did "drush updatedb".  The Drupal core update also caused several "projects" to be updated as well.

All of this seems to have cleared the problem I originally reported – I no longer see a long delay when I first log in and click CiviCRM.